# How can I use node "fs" in electron within angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, electron

I try to use Electron and Angular5 to write my first desktop App but unfortunately i am stuck in using the fs module. It seems that I have imported fs correctly (no errors within Visual Studio Code and code completion) but when i tried using "fs.readFile" the console prints out this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_fs__.readFile is not a function
```

This is the code of my service so far:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { OpenDialogOptions } from 'electron';

@Injectable()
export class FileService {

  dialog = this._electronService.remote.dialog;
  window = this._electronService.remote.getCurrentWindow();

  constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { }

  loadFileContent(): void{
    this.dialog.showOpenDialog(this.window, {},(fileNames) => {
      if(fileNames === undefined){
        console.error("no files selected!");
        return;
      }

      fs.readFile(fileNames[0], "utf-8", (err, data) => {
        if(err){
          console.error("Cannot read file ",err);
          return;
        }

        console.log("The content of the file is : ");
        console.log(data);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

Do I miss something here? Seems that fs is not loaded or something? Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of the comments from kimy82!

First i needed to get the Angular5 webpack.config.js by simply using:

```
ng eject
```

After that i opened up the webpack.config.js and added the following:

```
"target": "node-webkit"
```

Simply "node" did not work out for me and since electron uses a Chromium this should be ok.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Unfortunately solution no longer available on `angular6`: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10681

Comment: This is not a good suggestion unless you know the consequences of ejecting.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use remote.require to load native node modules from ngx-electron.

```
fs;

constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { 
    this.fs = this._electronService.remote.require('fs');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your browser cannot access the file system on the server. fs should not be loaded in the browser

Comment: Is there another way to access the filesystem within electron? It is made for Desktop Apps and not for server usage. Due to this post it is possible to access the filesystem but it has not been made in angular or with typescript so i cannot reproduce it: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/106/how-to-choose-read-save-delete-or-create-a-file-with-electron-framework

Comment: Depending on angular version you have access to webpack config. If you can change it. Set the target to be node. Might work.  _target: 'node',_

Comment: I ran ng eject now on my project to get the webpack config but that broke some buildfiles. get the error: Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined ... for polyfills.bundle.js, for styles.bundle.js for vendor.bundle.js and main.bundle.js ... i check the web for help but maybe you guys know something better?