# Angular 6 with lowdb - not getting it to work

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create an Electron app with Angular 6 that uses [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) as a local database.

It's all very new to me and it's trial and error, but I don't seem to be able to figure out how to overcome the following error:

I've installed lowdb in my application by using the commands

`npm install --save lowdb` *(edit: forgot to mention I did this already)*

and

`npm install --save @types/lowdb`

I've created a service to communicate with this "local database".

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import lowdb from 'lowdb';
import { default as FileAsync } from 'lowdb/adapters/FileAsync';
import { CurrentUserModel } from '../models/current-user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LowdbService {

  private db: lowdb.LowdbAsync;

  constructor() {
    this.initDatabase();
  }

  set( field: string, value: any ) {
    this.db.set( field, value ).write();
  }

  private async initDatabase() {
    const adapter = new FileAsync( 'db.json' );
    this.db = await lowdb( adapter );

    this.db.defaults( { user: CurrentUserModel } );
  }
}
```

But when I include the service in the constructor of a component I get errors.

```
ERROR in ./src/app/services/lowdb.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lowdb' in '/Users/paul/Projects/application-name/src/app/services'
ERROR in ./src/app/services/lowdb.service.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'lowdb/adapters/FileAsync' in '/Users/paul/Projects/application-name/src/app/services'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
ERROR in src/app/services/lowdb.service.ts(2,12): error TS1192: Module '"/Users/paul/Projects/application-name/node_modules/@types/lowdb/index"' has no default export.
src/app/services/lowdb.service.ts(3,14): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/paul/Projects/application-name/node_modules/@types/lowdb/adapters/FileAsync"' has no exported member 'default'.
```

As far as I can see I'm doing the same as mentioned in [this Github comment](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/issues/233#issuecomment-434501199) and [this Stackoverflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52063654/how-to-create-lowdb-in-typescriptmain-ts-angular). I can't find any more documentation though.

Can somebody help me out?

*Update*
Using `import * as lowdb from 'lowdb'` seemed to solve my initial errors. But it resulted in a few other errors. See below.

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'constants' in '/Users/paul/Projects/project-name/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/paul/Projects/project-name/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/paul/Projects/project-name/node_modules/graceful-fs'
ERROR in ./node_modules/graceful-fs/legacy-streams.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/Users/paul/Projects/project-name/node_modules/graceful-fs'
```

Comment: So you just installed `@types/lowdb`? That is only typings for that library, you need to install the library itself via `npm install --save lowdb` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you installed just @types/lowdb, that is only typings for that library, you need to install the library itself via:

```
npm install --save lowdb
```

Then, looks like there is no default export so `import lowdb from 'lowdb';` also won't work. Try is like this:

```
import { LowdbAsync } from 'lowdb';
import * as lowdb from 'lowdb';
import * as FileAsync from 'lowdb/adapters/FileAsync';

private db: LowdbAsync<any>; // TODO provide correct schema instead of any

private async initDatabase() {
  const adapter = new FileAsync('db.json');
  this.db = await lowdb(adapter);

  this.db.defaults({ user: any });
}
```

Or you can try removing those typings (as they might be outdated) and do what their docs says:

https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/tree/master/examples#browser

```
import low from 'lowdb'
import LocalStorage from 'lowdb/adapters/LocalStorage'
```

(but when you take a look at `@types/lowdb`, there is no such default export so again, the typings might be outdated)

As for your other issue, take a look here:

https://github.com/typicode/lowdb/issues/206#issuecomment-324884867

> typicode commented on 25 Aug 2017
>
> @DickyKwok I think it's impossible. Can you answer this, @typicode?
>
> I confirm, to save to disk using FileSync or FileAsync adapters you need to have access to Node fs API.

Looks like you should use `LocalStorage` adapter instead.

Another similar issue here: [How can I use node "fs" in electron within angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47883109/how-can-i-use-node-fs-in-electron-within-angular-5)

You could also try the solution proposed in one of answers there:

https://github.com/ThorstenHans/ngx-electron

```
constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { 
    this.fs = this._electronService.remote.require('fs');
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I also did install lowdb from npm.
"Import star as" seemed to solve the errors I mentioned.
But it opened up a lot of new errors. I've added them as an update to my original question.

Comment: I think you should use `LocalStorage` adapter instead, take a look at updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your lowdb is missing in node_modules.

try

```
npm install lowdb
```